# Error: "undefined local variable or method 'e'" inside RegistrationsController

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues passing the email from my JS to Rails using Stripe Checkout. I keep getting error `undefined local variable or method 'e'` on line 21 and 25 via stack trace. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

**Rails code:**

```
def create
   **line 21:** @registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: stripe_params[:stripeEmail],
                                                               card_token: stripe_params[:stripeToken]) //ERROR
    raise "Please, check registration errors" unless @registration.valid?
    @registration.process_payment
    @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
  rescue
    **line 25:** flash[:error] = e.message // ERROR
    render :new
  end
```

**JS code:**

```
<script src='https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js'></script>
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_xxxxxx',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  jQuery('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'The Climb',
      description: 'Individual',
      email: 'asdfasdf999@asdf.com',
      amount: 3500
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 24 should be:

```
rescue => e
```